# Unable to access localhost:3000 from other machine

Tags: node.js

I'm having a node.js application running on **localhost:3000** and able to access it through my browser. I'm having the following configuration in my server.js file.
     here port is 3000

```
app.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', function onStart(err) {
if (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
console.info('==>  Listening on port %s. Open up http://localhost:%s/ in your browser.', port);
});
```

When I try to access my server using my laptop's IP by checking it through **what's my ip** on google e.g. ip is **http://58.27.123.12:3000**, it doesn't take me to the requested page. I'm running the application on **Ubuntu 19.10**.
I'm also able to **ping** my ip through other systems and it responds successfully. What I might be doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to connect from your local network? If you don't, you'll need *port forwarding*.

Comment: Yeah. I'm trying to connect through local network and it isn't responding as explained above. I need to access it from another system which is outside to my network as well.

Comment: @CoderCharmander how do I achieve that?

Comment: Google port forwarding and do the appropriate steps for your router. And from the local network, if you don't use port forwarding, connect with your local ip (usually beginning with `192.168`)

Comment: Did you check the firewall and port openness?

Comment: Check firewall rules https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/ufw-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands

Comment: @NageshSanika I've implemented that change but still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want people to access on LAN give them your localIP with port number or if you want to provide access via internet check below links:-

https://localhost.run/

https://localtunnel.github.io/www/

```
ssh -R 80:localhost:3000 ssh.localhost.run
```

using this command solved the issue after installing localtunnel

Comment: lt --port 3000 
 doesn't gives any link.

Comment: Do I need to have a static ip to complete this task?

Comment: localtunnel is down for some reason.try localhost.run using this command ssh -R 80:localhost:3000 ssh.localhost.run

Comment: How does it really work? Do you have any ideas? I would like to know its back-end working.